# Calculate the number of rows filled with numbers in a big array

Tags: arrays

I created a menu that one of the option is "calculate average number"
I have a 2000 rows of numbers in a text file.
I use fstream and put them in array but I had to set the array size as 2100 because there is another option which is 
" Add a new employee " which means if I add a new employee detail it will become 2001 rows.

So the problem is how should I check the number of rows which filled with numbers?
I tried search for some solution and some are these

```
int rows = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

but instead of show the current number of rows which filled with numbers it shows the array size I set (2100)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a std::vector.  Add elements to it using push_back(), get the number of elements using size().

If you want to still use arrays, the logic that reads data would need to return the number of entries it read  (e.g. size_t n = readLines("myfile.txt"); ).  Or if you know of some value you'll never encounter you can prefill the array with that value (e.g. -1) so when processing the read data you can stop once that value is found.  However, be aware the array method might someday fail if you don't have enough space for all the entries in the file.